# Angular - Hostlistener window:scroll function does not called after page reload

Tags: javascript, angular

I have used following HostListener to sticky a menu top of page when scolling down.

```
sticky = false;

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  handleScroll(): void {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 150) {
      this.sticky = true;
    } else {
      this.sticky = false;
    }
  }
```

It works well but after reload the page, The handleScroll() function is not callled

Comment: why it should call that? if you did not scroll?

Comment: Why not use `position: sticky` in CSS? Then you wouldn't need JS for that. If you really need to use JS, have a look at [intersection observer.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Answer (score 0):

Call this method also in `ngOnInit` and then it is solved. Because when you reload page, the scroll event is not fired, because you do not scroll.